# how to get linux service stop and start information

Tags: linux

How can I check when and who started or stopped a linux demon?

example: I want to check who stopped httpd and when.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your system, you can look in log files like `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/secure` for users using `sudo` to run the appropriate command, or to get a privileged shell. The command `last` will also show when people logged in and out.

Comment: I have a follow-up question to this: Say you have two users who are explicitely granted rights to start a certain service, so they don't need to use sudo. Assuming they were both logged in at about the same time, would you be able to find out who of them started or stopped the service?

Comment: There is no guarantee that you can get this info. Another (unreliable) place to look is inside each user's ~/.bash_history for the commands they gave. You could setup  the auditctl system for the future to log who runs the given command, though it seems a bit complicated.